# Is there a built in check-in policy for TFS 2008 requiring comments?

Tags: .net, tfs

I am trying to force users to enter comments when checking code into TFS 2008.  I found [this post](http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/02/27/2302.aspx) from Jeff Atwood explaining how to add a new policy enforcing this behavior, but the post is dated. Has this been added to TFS?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [TFS power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx#checkin). Look towards the bottom for the check-in policy pack.