# Team Foundation Service Mandatory Comments on check in

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm using Microsoft's new Team Foundation Service, http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

I wanted to know whether it was possible to make comments mandatory on check-in, e.g. if I check-in a change without a comment an error will be thrown and my commit rejected.

Comment: Isn't a meaningless comment just as useless as an empty comment?  Since TFS can't check comments for meaning, I'm not sure this facility would help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a built in check-in policy for TFS 2008 requiring comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702503/is-there-a-built-in-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2008-requiring-comments)

Comment: If a developer is adding "meaningless" comments at the point of check-in then I would be seriously questioning their suitability on the project, I would also be checking their code with a fine tooth comb. Adding blank comments and/or meaningless comments speaks volumes about the pride that you take in your own work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Visual Studio (2012).

- Open "Team Explorer".
- Select your "Team Project".
- Click "Settings".
- Under the "Team Project" heading click "Source Control".
- Select the "Check-in Policy" Tab.
- Click "Add..."
- Select "Changeset Comments Policy".

[image: Changeset Comment Policy]

In Visual Studio 2010, you will have to install the [Team Foundation Power Toys](http://aka.ms/tfpt) on all client machines - those without it installed will not be able to check in code.