# TFS Comment Policy bringing override window even when comment supplied

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have recently issued a Changeset Comment Policy in my team projects, following the steps at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13981350/2713582.

Thing is, even when someone supplies a comment on the changeset, it still shows up a policy override window, stating that the field is blank. Oddly enough, It does not happen in my machine.

We're using VSOnline, alongside with VS2010 and Windows (8.1 / 10).

Did anyone ever face this issue?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Team Services, or are you using TFS 2010?

Comment: @DanielMann Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: `VSOnline, alongside with TFS2010` Are you meaning  that you are using VSTS and VS2010? Could they check in the code successfully ?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the error in the post. Yeah, VSTS + VS2010.
They can, but even when typing the changeset comment, they still have to write an override policy statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VS2010 and can't check in the code.You have missed the last paragraph with the above tutorials page.

*Note:* In Visual Studio 2010, you will have to install the [Team Foundation Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) on all client machines - those without it installed will not be able to check in code.

Comment: Indeed, that is true. Missed that line :| Thanks!